# How to get the size of QGraphicsView that is in a layout?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I'm new to Qt programming and I am developing a drawing application. I have a class `MyWidget` which has a member `QGraphicsView`. `MyWidget` is a member of another class `MainWidget` (which has other widgets as well and all of them are in a layout).MainWidget is the central widget of my subclass of `QMainWindow`.

I have created functions to scale the view with the mouse wheel event and a function to drag the scene around.

The problem is - I want to set the Scene's size to be fixed, and to be 3 times the size of the view, but since the view is managed by a layout in order to take as much space as possible I can't get the view's size?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `size` property will give you the **current** size of your widget:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#size-prop

Alternatively, you could subclass QGraphicsView and re-implement the `resizeEvent`:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#resizeEvent

For a full example, have a look into:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-scribble.html

Comment: Thank you @Hurzelchen. The size function helped me and I managed to do what I wanted without subclassing QGraphicsView, but I still have a problem.
I set the scene's size, only when the mainwindow is maximized (in order to get the maximum visible area of the view). For that purpose I tried showMaximized(), but it's not working properly, so I re-implemented the QMainwindow::changeEvent and I check to see if the state is windowMaximized. This seems to work and everything is fine, but only after you click the Maximize button of the window frame. 
Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely get the view's size. There are two ways to go about it:

1. Attach an event filter object to your view: `myView->installEventFilter(filterObject)`. The `filterObject`'s `eventFilter` method will be invoked for all events reaching your view, including resize events.
2. Use a custom view class and reimplement `resizeEvent`. This method gets called each time the widget is resized. Do note that designer allows you to add custom classes without having to write plugins.